# Why && lightning expression operator doesn't work?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

According to this [reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm) the syntax below:

`<aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.isVisible,!empty(v.subjectsList))}">`

should be equivalent to:

`<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isVisible && !empty(v.subjectsList)}">`

However, I receive the message below when I try to save the lightning component to the sandbox:

```
FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION - c:SubjectSelectionView_GCC:69,34: ParseError at [row,col]:[70,34]
Message: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.: Source
```

So, What am I missing?

Comment: Brought this to [Salesforce Docs' attention](https://twitter.com/jayantkdas/status/1088096993908613121), and they have acknowledged it to be included in the docs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `&&` you can use `&amp;&amp;` (the HTML entity for &). That seems to satisfy the parser and the expression will still execute your logic correctly.

So your code will be:

`<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isVisible &amp;&amp; !empty(v.subjectsList)}">`

**Edit**

As noted in the comments, it's probably better to use `and` like:

`<aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.isVisible, !empty(v.subjectsList))}">`

Comment: @JayantDas No, Lightning requires it. It is not specific to the Developer Console. Go ahead and try it out in your favorite IDE. ... It's technically an oversight in the documentation, as far as I can tell. Aura has always worked this way.

Comment: [AND function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm) is more readable in case we have 2 parameters: `<aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.isVisible, !empty(v.subjectsList))}">`

Comment: @sfdcfox that's new to me. I recollect using at least `||` at places and thought `&&` would be the same.

Comment: @JayantDas yeah, the .cmp file is parsed as XML, and follows the rules of XML precisely. & is the start of a character entity like `&gt;` and `&amp;`.

Comment: @JohnTowers +1 for the sharing this, a new learning today. Everyday is a new day in Salesforce.

Comment: Seems far preferable to just use `and`.

Comment: Brought this to [Salesforce Docs' attention](https://twitter.com/jayantkdas/status/1088096993908613121), and they have acknowledged it to be included in the docs.